# What is the difference between using ffmpeg-php extension and FFmpeg binaries with PHP?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

As the subject implies ..
What is the difference between the library in this link
    http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
and the php-ffmpeg extension which we install it on wamp (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't complicated.  One is simply a standalone FFmpeg binary that you can run from a terminal or other application.  The PHP extension version is... a PHP extension.

If you were to use regular FFmpeg binaries, you could use PHP's `exec()` to run them, like you would run any external application.

Alternatively by using the PHP extension, you get extra functions within PHP itself that you can call to run FFmpeg functionality.  It's a native binding that may also be more efficient.

Personally, I recommend going the route of a regular FFmpeg binary for portability.  I've found that building the PHP extension is difficult, and almost nobody has it installed.  On the other hand, it's very easy to find an FFmpeg binary so you don't have to build it yourself, and it isn't difficult to handle its STDIO streams depending on what you need to do.

Comment: So, if I were to use the binary version, what is the suitable version for a shared linux hosting ? (from the link I posted above)

And thanks so much for your useful answer.

Comment: @HazemTaha For shared hosting you will likely have to depend on your host to install it.  It's rare that you will be able to upload your own binaries and execute them from your scripts.  Rarer still is a shared hosting provider that will let you use long-running scripts, such as those you will need to interface with FFmpeg.  Contact your host.  Alternatively, get a cheap VPS and then run whatever you'd like. There is a link in my profile to Digital Ocean which is pretty cheap. If you use that link, you can get a month or two for free on their cheapest $5 box. There are other providers as well.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll try this link.
btw, I have root access to the centos shared hosting but I need to know how to install the ffmpeg-php extension to it ? could you help me with this ?

Comment: @HazemTaha There are a lot of different builds of FFmpeg out there, with different capabilities.  Installation on CentOS can be particularly difficult.  I can't help you with it... you'll have to try it yourself.  I have a script for Ubuntu you could paste in, but not CentOS.  And, I thought you were going to use the regular binary, rather than the PHP extension version?  Try just downloading these and running them:  http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: The problem is that I'm asked to edit a website's scripts which uses the PHP extension version, so I have to use the extension rather than the binary version because I don't want to make major changes to the code.

Thanks so much :)

Comment: @HazemTaha Ah, well for that then how you install the extension depends on your PHP version and where you have PHP installed.  Usually it isn't difficult.  Just drop the `.so` file in the right place, and add it to your PHP.ini file with the other extensions.

Comment: Thanks so much Brad for you answer.